# How to join to the max date of the second table less than a date on the first

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

I have a table of views, which have user_id and view_date

```
-- 29,909,611 rows
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views v
```

I also have a table of subscriptions which has user_id and created_at. A user will likely have multiple entries because each renewal will be a new record (monthly or annually).

I want to link each view to the active subscription at the time, which is the subscription with the max created_at less than the view_date.

Some views do not have a subscription hence the first left join.

The count is just for debug purposes. I would expect the rows for the below query to be exactly the same as the total views. I don't understand why it is less as the left join is present.

```
-- 25,956,872 rows
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views v
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscriptions s1 ON v.user_id = s1.user_id AND s1.created_at < v.view_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscriptions s2 ON v.user_id = s2.user_id AND s1.created_at < s2.created_at
WHERE s2.id IS NULL
```

This is for use on Azure Synapse so some of the more esoteric SQL might not work.

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of this line? I assume it's the problem. I think it's acting on the whole query and therefore reducing the number of rows.

```
WHERE s2.id IS NULL
```

Maybe this would work since it would only act on the second LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views v
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscriptions s1 ON v.user_id = s1.user_id AND s1.created_at < v.view_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscriptions s2 ON v.user_id = s2.user_id AND s1.created_at < s2.created_at AND s2.id IS NULL
```

If you're able to use OUTER APPLY, I think this is the solution:

```
SELECT v.*, t1.*
FROM views v
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM subscriptions s
    WHERE v.user_id = s.user_id AND s.created_at < v.view_date
    ORDER BY s.created_at DESC) t1
```

Comment: Great use for the outer apply.

Comment: Thankyou, I'll experiment with this and come back to you!